# Why don't we have an actual question on our About page?

Tags: support

I was looking at Ask Different's About page and saw the following question as our example:

[image]

Why don't we have a 'proper' question? I'm sure we used to, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it got de-selected, but I have chosen a new question from the ones we get to pick.

Comment: Great! I presumed you got to pick any question — out of interest, what's the criteria for a question to be allowed on that page?

Comment: I think there was some older discussion here and certainly on the main meta - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211190/ and I even [asked for moderators to get notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164516/please-ping-moderators-whenever-the-sites-about-page-gets-modified) when things changed, but there likely wasn't enough value seen for that to be coded.